# where to include json web token

Tags: jwt

I maybe missing an important piece of jwt concept but I'm having a hard time finding info on where the server is supposed to include the generated json web token in the response and where the client is supposed to include it in the subsequent requests. Are there any rules/guidelines/best practices on that?

Answer (score 0):

The JWT should be sent to the client in the response body. In the subsequent requests you've got to include an header field called **Authorization** with the token.

Check this [link](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/) for more details.